# how do we identify lint format check format

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

I am working in a python code base that throws this error when I run the the command

```
make test



Oh no!   
1 file would be reformatted, 28 files would be left unchanged.
make: *** [auto-format-check] Error 1
```

My question is, how do I identify which line has the formatting issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't, you `git add` the file then apply the autoformat to fix the problem (probably black seeing your output?). Once you have applied the autoformatter you can check `git diff` to see what changed.

Comment: what is the command for this please?

Comment: I tried with this command black --check --diff <filename>

Comment: ``black .`` apply black on everything recursively. You can also use ``pre-commit`` so it's done when committing to git.